# The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: monodevelop

I tried to compile my new application in MonoDevelop and I got this error:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.203/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(5,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.DependencyContextBuilder:_filteredPackages'
>   (12) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000027 from typeref
>   (expected class 'NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity' in assembly
>   'NuGet.Packaging, Version=5.0.0.6, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35') assembly:NuGet.Packaging,
>   Version=5.0.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   type:NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity member:(null)
>         at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute () [0x00000] in :0 
>         at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00029] in <58f0218f988743a48dd7c84cbe933f4e>:0 
>         at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x001f6]
>   in <58f0218f988743a48dd7c84cbe933f4e>:0  (MSB4018) (passcracker)

I cannot compile any application. Please help.

Answer (score 98):

I had the same problem using **.Net Standard 2.1**, and I solved it for myself by **cleaning** the solution and then **rebuilding** it.

Comment: I deleted all existing packages from **C:\Users\YourUserName\.nuget\packages**. Please note that there is dot before "nuget". Tried rebuilding and it worked.

Comment: @code_disciple that made me chuckle, thanks! On a serious note, the clean and rebuild worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

Just moved my projects to a new machine (copying, not pulling from GIT) and started getting this. Deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders in each project solved this issue.

Comment: Worked for me in vs2019 .net core 3.1

Comment: You might run a "Restore NUGET Packages" on the solution after that, either by right-clicking on the solution and selecting the command or via CLI: `nuget restore MySolution.sln`

Comment: For solutions with many projects the following PowerShell one-liner may be useful.  It deletes all bin and obj folders under the current folder (so run it from the solution root): `get-childitem 'bin','obj' -directory -recurse | remove-item -recurse`. It will recursively search for sub-folders of the working folder with "bin" or "obj" in the path (ie it will search sub-folders, and sub-sub-folders, etc) and then will recursively delete the folders it finds and their contents.

Answer (score 5):

Your combination of Mono MSBuild and .NET Core SDK is incompatible because they use different versions of the internal NuGet library. To resolve this problem, you can:

- Downgrade .NET Core SDK to 2.1.5xx or 2.2.1xx (for example, 2.1.505 or 2.2.108)
- Upgrade Mono to 6.0

You can find a detailed explanation of this problem and possible solutions here: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004180039

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2540).

The only fix at this stage seems to be to downgrade to .NET Core v2.2.105.

To downgrade:

- [Uninstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions) the latest .NET Core version (v2.2.2+).
- [Download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) and install v2.2.105.

Comment: Just for others who find this post, I'm using VS for Mac 7.7.4, I had to delete the dotnet sdk from '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk' manually and install v2.2.107 (x64) from the above provided link. This version is the only one that did not throw any error for me

Comment: Adding this to the list that still fails : /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(5,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 install of 2.2.105 link : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-2.2.105

Comment: After using that microsoft link, the "install" command line failed (I still needed the setup commands listed at the article).  But this command finally worked : sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-2.2=2.2.105-1

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and after reading comments, I was able to resolve by combining comments - First deleted bin folder, obj folder, executed clean command, deleted [image] and then rebuilded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community this is a pretty silly comment, they've included an image that didn't work due to their rep < 50 and now you're saying edit it to make it better?!!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error happen and the slove for me was correcting the Package version number in .csproj file .

```
   <Version>2.0.7.</Version> <!--casued the error-->

   <Version>2.0.7</Version> <!--this fixed the error-->
```

Removing the trailing '.' fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following CMD in the `*.sln` folder. This will delete all your OBJ and BIN folders automatically. And your issue will be solved.

```
FOR /d /r . %%d in (bin,obj) DO ( IF EXIST "%%d" ( ECHO %%d | FIND /I "\node_modules\" > Nul && ( ECHO.Skipping: %%d ) || ( ECHO.Deleting: %%d rd /s/q "%%d" )))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in migration from `.Net Framework 4.5` to `.NET 6.0` (with the 70 project).

All of the above answers are correct, but they were not enough for my problem.

I use this answer:

> Deleting the `bin` and `obj` and `.vs` folders then Clean Solution and
> Rebuild Solution

it's working in `Build` Mode, not `Rebuild`. And the problem remained.

> I update the `Version` of `SDK` , but not enough and I have the problem.

I realized this:

> `duplicate property` (or variables) with the same name (or similar Name) in `derived` classes.

It was a good solution and a few problems were solved.

finally (after the 3 days), The biggest problem I noticed was that I had `Loop References`.

I fixed The `Loop References` in projects and the error is solved.

Comment: any chance you can explain how you discovered that Loop References were your issue?

Comment: @iwantwin, It's funny, but it's the truth, with trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the file. For instance, Add prefix _ or #; so, it cannot be used.

Restart Visual Studio, then try to build. If still problem is there, needs to restart the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had .net standard project built on .net standard 2.0. Yesterday I updated my Visual Studio 2019 to 16.3.0 to leverage .Net Core 3.0. But all of sudden build of project targeting on standard 2.0 started throwing *"GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly* error.

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the target framework to 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<DelaySign>false</DelaySign>` in your .csproj file remove it to solve this Problem.

Answer (score 0):

in vs code i got this error, after trying some solution from forms, i found solution in deleting bin and obj foldersfrom project and build again.
this solved my problem.
vs code version: 1.53.1
dotnet version : 5

Answer (score 0):

I had it after updating vs 2019 community,
Delete bin & obj folders,
then clean & build the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project that somehow was referencing its own dll from another project bin file. I have no idea how it was generated

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="PBS.Hypercomb.Model">
    <HintPath>..\PBS.Hypercomb.Services\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\PBS.Hypercomb.Model.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

This was within PBS.Hypercomb.Model project. Removing it seems to have fixed it.