# What is "The 'GenerateDepsFile' task failed unexpectedly." error when Rebuild the project?

Tags: asp.net-core

I ported multiple ASP.net 4.7.2 projects to ASP.net Core 3.0 (one solution) using VS2019. Once I setup everything I "Build" project and got all successful.

[image]

However when I click on "Rebuild" project I get the error "**The 'GenerateDepsFile' task failed unexpectedly.**"

[image]

Why is this ? How to solve it ?

Project "DBDataStructures" has typical standard C# class definitions. No third party classes used.

Comment: Expand the error message and share us the details, is there any detail error message in the build output? Which asp.net core 3.0 version did you use?

Comment: [This is apparently a know issue requiring a downgrade of .Net Core at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914055/1612190)